# PHP-CGI process crashing twice a day in a wordpress hosted Dedicated Server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, php-cgi

CGI process is crashing twice a day and comes up after apache httpd process restart.
I am running CentOS 6.3 Server , 16GB ram, i5 Quad core processor. With just only one wordpress blog running with site traffic around 40,000-50,000 impressions. During that time iam observing outage in my wordpress site. Here are my TOP command logs after and before restart showing PHP-CGI process comes to live after httpd restart.

```
top - 08:17:25 up 4 days,  1:15,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.09,
0.28 Tasks: 294 total,   1 running, 273 sleeping,   0 stopped,  20 zombie Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,
0.0%si,  0.0%st Mem:  16260432k total, 11240088k used,  5020344k free,   214684k buffers Swap:  2047992k total,        0k used,  2047992k free,
656664k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
2124 drweb     20   0  180m 177m 1712 S  0.0  1.1  18:17.11
drwebd.real          2990 drweb     20   0  180m 175m  336 S  0.0  1.1 0:00.00
drwebd.real          2991 drweb     20   0  180m 175m  336 S 0.0  1.1   0:00.00
drwebd.real          2992 drweb     20   0  180m 175m  336 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.00
drwebd.real          2989 drweb     20 0  180m 175m  332 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.00
drwebd.real          1907
mysql     20   0 2175m 116m 7228 S  0.0  0.7  61:41.00 mysqld
16436 root      30  10  235m  49m 2964 S  0.0  0.3   0:02.83 spamd
16440 popuser   30  10  235m  47m 1028 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 spamd
16441 popuser   30  10  235m  47m 1028 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.01 spamd
24175 root      20   0  386m  21m  10m S  0.0  0.1   0:02.59 httpd
1975 named     20   0  379m  21m 2512 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.08 named
9438 apache    20   0  386m  13m 2424 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.07 httpd
9215 apache    20   0  386m  13m 2420 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.08 httpd
11036 apache    20   0  386m  13m 2416 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 httpd
10197 apache    20   0  386m  13m 2416 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 httpd

[root@ip-173-201-253-36 marketcalls]# service httpd restart
Stopping > httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting > httpd:                                            [  OK  ]

top - 08:18:05 up 4 days,  1:15,  1 user,  load average: 1.38, 0.44,
0.38 Tasks: 318 total,   5 running, 312 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie Cpu(s): 23.1%us,  7.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 69.2%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,
0.0%si,  0.0%st Mem:  16260432k total, 12860340k used,  3400092k free,   214688k buffers Swap:  2047992k total,        0k used,  2047992k free,
1181288k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11481 redcry    20   0  321m 115m  42m R 38.1  0.7   0:06.27 php-cgi
11545 redcry    20   0  307m 101m  42m S 36.8  0.6   0:05.78 php-cgi
11482 redcry    20   0  317m 111m  42m S 26.2  0.7   0:05.74 php-cgi
11379 redcry    20   0  310m 104m  42m R  9.6  0.7   0:04.25 php-cgi
11381 redcry    20   0  308m 102m  42m R  7.3  0.6   0:05.64 php-cgi
1907 mysql     20   0 2175m 115m 7228 S  2.0  0.7  61:42.10 mysqld
15 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.32 migration/3
11575 apache    20   0  386m  13m 2388 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.01 httpd
11698 root      20   0 15160 1408  936 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.07 top
1 root      20   0 19356 1552 1244 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.85 init
2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.42 migration/0
4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.59 ksoftirqd/0
5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.19 watchdog/0
7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.74 migration/1
8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
```

**These are from my error logs when the PHP-CGI crashed got crashed:**

```
[Tue Feb 05 08:07:13 2013] [notice] child pid 9468 exit signal Bus error (7)
[Tue Feb 05 08:07:14 2013] [notice] child pid 11009 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Feb 05 08:07:15 2013] [notice] child pid 9819 exit signal Bus error (7)
[Tue Feb 05 08:07:21 2013] [notice] child pid 10276 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Can any one tell me how to trouble shoot  the above error log?

Answer (score 0):

Ug. Well, the usual method is [getting apache to coredump](http://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/mar/6/fixing-apache-segmentation-faults-caused-php/) but that also causes a lot of insecurity, and should never be done on a production machine. You can also try [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/index.php). Have you changed anything recently?